# Is there an orthonormal basis of the Sobolev space $H^{1}(\Omega)$ with uniformly bounded elements?

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure, sobolev-spaces

Does there exist a Hilbert (i.e., orthonormal) basis of the Sobolev space $ H^{1}(\Omega)$ with almost all bounded elements: say by 1?

Here, $\Omega$ is an open connected subset of $\mathbb{R^{3}}$.

Comment: What is your definition of Hilbert basis?

Comment: What is $\Omega$? What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: By Hilbert basis, i mean an orthonormal basis. \Omega is an open connected subset of \mathbb{R^{3}}.

Comment: @zaq I don't see what you mean. If $\Omega = [0,1]^n$ then the Fourier series give an orthonormal bounded basis for $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_{[0,1]^n} (f(x) \overline{g(x)}+\sum_{j=1}^n \partial_{x_j} f(x) \overline{\partial_{x_j}g(x)})dx$, right ?